# how to display one data based on the latest date that does not have the same data

Tags: mysql

I have difficulty displaying one data that does not have similarity based on the latest date

```
CREATE TABLE t_sport (
id INT(1) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
playing VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
tanggal DATE);

INSERT INTO `t_sport` (`name`,`playing`,`tanggal`) VALUES 
('Feri','Football','2015-06-12'),
('Feri','Football','2017-11-12'),
('Feri','Football','2019-11-30'),
('Feri','Volley ball','2019-12-05'), 
('sugy','Football','2019-11-30');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d8147/1

```
id name playing      tanggal
 1 Feri Football     2015-06-12
 2 Feri Football     2017-11-12
 3 Feri Football     2019-11-30
 4 Feri Volley ball  2019-12-05
 5 sugy Football     2019-11-30
```

expected display results

```
id name playing      tanggal
 3 Feri Football     2019-11-30
 4 Feri Volley ball  2019-12-05
 5 sugy Football     2019-11-30
```

please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Fiddles are great but you should try to explain the problem here

Comment: I have difficulty displaying one data that has no similarity based on the latest date

Answer (score 1):

seems you need  the max data for each  name, playing

```
select name, playing, max(tanggal) 
from t_sport
group by  name, playing
```

for this you can use aggregated  function max() and group by clause

Answer (score 0):

this query can fetch your expected result

```
select name, playing, max(tanggal) from t_sport group by  name, playing;
```